# Direction in solving multi-object query

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, class

I am trying to build a trigger that does a few things and I was hoping I could get the best direction in handling this.

I have 2 objects ("**Quote**" and "**QuoteLine**") and a custom setting called "**ServiceDate__c**" which basically stores 2 information, *Country__c* and *numberOfDays__c*.
The goal of the trigger is to query a *Country__c* field on the **QuoteLine** object, compare it to *country* field on the **ServiceDate__c** object to get the number.

---

> For Example, on the quote line, we store country names like USA. On
>   the Custom setting, we have a map that stores Country, USA with a
>   ServiceDate value of 50. 50 is the number of days that needs to be
>   added to the close date on the quote line. So it's be closeDate *2016-01-20 + 50.*

---

Finally, since there will be a number of *closeDate__c* fields on the **QuoteLine**, I would like to query only the UNIQUE *CloseDate__c* values and update the  **Quote** object.

Sample code would be appreciated.

Tl:dr. Get unique date values on the **Quote** after calculation happens on the **Quoteline** object that references a custom setting for more information.

Here is what I have so a far;

```
trigger SB_QuoteAdditionalUpdates on SBQQ__Quote__c (before insert, before update) {

  Set<id> QuoteIds = New Set<id>();

  for (SBQQ__Quote__c SBQuotes : trigger.new){

    QuoteIds.add(SBQuotes.id);
    SBQQ__QuoteLine__c[] SBQuoteLines = [Select country__c, country_code__c, close_date__c, country_employee_construct__c, Employee_CountFormula__c 
                                                   from SBQQ__QuoteLine__c 
                                                   where id IN: QuoteIds];

    if(SBQuoteLines.size()>0){
        for(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c SBQuoteLine : SBQuoteLines ){

          map<id, OperationalStartDate__c> NumberOfDaysMap = 
               new map <id, OperationalStartDate__c>([select name, Number_Of_Days__c 
                                                       from OperationalStartDate__c 
                                                    where name =: SBQuoteLine.country__c ]);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: oh dear, you are doing soql inside of for loops - this needs to be bulkified. Check documentation on tips for doing this